# PHP: How to get only the current folder of a website

Tags: php

For example I have a website that points to a page like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/folder/file
```

How can I get determine /folder so that I can go further an quote an if statement like

```
if /folder then echo something
```

Why do I need this?

I am trying to tell facebook which image to pick from a page. Actually I have a pretty simple page structure and the image that facebook should take is always at first but somehow it does choose another one from time to time. I guess because the other images are loaded faster. And the old way to rel="img_src" doesn't seem to work anymore as that I could just add it to the wanted image.

So well of course I use the open graph protocol to tell facebook which Image it should use.

I am working with a cms were I can output the path of the image depending on the id the image has. I have two different id's for the different kind of pages living in two different folders.

This leads to:

```
if index --> echo meta og for index img
else if /folderone (with id1) --> echo meta og for id1
else if /foldertwo (with id2) --> echo meta og for id2
```

This is why I need to know the foldername.

Now with the answer I have following setup, just that you know:

```
<?php $folder = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>

<?php if (dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == "/") echo "<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.mysite.com/img/img.jpg'/>" ;?>
<?php if (dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == "/folderOne") echo "<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.mysite.com/img/{$img_id1}'/> " ;?>
<?php if (dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == "/folderTwo") echo "<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.mysite.com/img/{$img_id2}'/> " ;?>
```

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? Maybe we can think of a better/easier way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does my answer not solve this issue? (you have made updates since I posted. just wondering if there was anything you were confused about)_

Comment: I am trying your answer out right now, just a second. I am not an expert with php, you must know.

Comment: I am just confused as to whether or not you want the CWD or the first segment of your URI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$script = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
echo dirname($script);
```

Answer (score 8):

[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) & 
[explode](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

gives you

```
/folder/file
```

then you can *explode()* to separate the path values and check the first one to see if it is 'folder'

Example here: http://tehplayground.com/#7TIKAwp6J
Example code:

```
$url = "http://www.mysite.com/folder/file";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$arr = explode("/",$path);
echo $arr[1]; // leading slash makes [0] ""
```

outputs

> folder

Comment: as $arr = explode("/",$path);  then use $arr[0]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But maybe I understand to less about php yet to really appreciate this code. The accepted answer was exactly what I needed. But vote up of course. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, they do provide you with different information, in this case both coincidentally (i think) provide the same results. Mine gives you the first part of the URI segment, the accepted answer gives you current script's path. This is useful for pages which need to point to themselves. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for more information

Comment: Thank's for the additional info! I will definitely refer back to this answer when it comes to your described case.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly use "get current working directory" function `getcwd()`?

1. Explode it by directory separator.
2. Then grab the last element like this:

   ```
   $var = getcwd();
   $var = explode('\\', $var); // your OS might use '/' instead
   $var = end($var);
   ```

I suppose this assumes you're not using some kind of MVC framework that uses routing.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is nicer than exploding the string:

```
function getCurrentDirectory(){
    $curDirPath = getcwd();
    return substr($curDirPath, strrpos($curDirPath, '/') + 1);
}
```

`getcwd()` gives you the current directory's path, and then you can truncate it starting right after the last occurrence of the `/` in its file path.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir_list = explode('/', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
$this_folder = $dir_list[count($dir_list)-1];
...
if ($this_folder) == "folderOne") echo "...."
...
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(dirname('yoursite/folder')){
```